# Can Reactive Extensions (Rx) be used across process or machine boundaries?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

Vaguely remember seeing some discussions on this quite a while back but haven't heard anything since. So basically are you able to subscribe to an IObservable on a remote machine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use IObservable.Remotable to use observables directly from other machines via .NET Remoting.

Comment: Hi Paul, do you have a link to an article of some sort that explains what it is and how it works?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(VS.71).aspx describes Remoting - be aware though, that Remoting has some pretty significant caveats when it comes to versioning (i.e. computer A has build 1004 and computer B has 1007 => app is broken)

Comment: thanks, actually I was looking for examples of IObservable.Remotable as I haven't come across it with the previous version of Rx :-P Found it anyway, on the Channel9 video I posted below

Answer (score 5):

Found this cool video on Channel 9 which an example of using *IObservable.Remotable* as Paul pointed out:

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/J.Van.Gogh/Whats-different-about-the-3-versions-of-Rx-Part-3-NET-35-SP1/

Very interesting stuff, gonna spend a bit of time playing around with it now! :-D

Comment: This video is not there anymore. anyone knows where it can be found?

Answer (score 5):

Another possible solution could be to use named pipes.

There is an excellent NuGet package [NamedPipeWrapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NamedPipeWrapper/1.4.0), see the [source on GitHub](https://github.com/acdvorak/named-pipe-wrapper). It would be easy to write a thin RX wrapper over this, i.e. subscribe to the RX stream and push the messages out to other .NET listening processes using this library.

As this solution uses named pipes, it would be a true pub/sub solution which would support multiple subscribers in different processes.

**Update**

It is indeed very easy to write simple RX bridge code over the named pipes library. Use an RX `Subject` and insert the RX bridge code into the event handlers. Its not more than 4 lines of additional code at both ends. I can post the code if anyone is interested.

**Update**

For more information on named pipes, see [.NET 3.5 Adds Named Pipes Support](http://tech.pro/tutorial/752/dotnet-35-adds-named-pipes-support) and [Interprocess Communication Using .NET 3.5 Named Pipes IO](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Interprocess-Communication-858cc9c7). The aforementioned NuGet package `NamedPipeWrapper` is a much nicer version of the built-in support for named pipes that .NET 3.5 introduced.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Check out [Pushqa](http://blog.petegoo.com/Pushqa/).

- Its easy to use. I was up and running in about 5 minutes.
- It works with C# .NET, WPF, ASP.NET or Javascript. SignalR is built into ASP.NET, but it works for any C# .NET project if you add the right NuGet package.
- It is superior to RX over .NET remoting (see my other answer), as we can have one server and many subscribers (it is a true pub/sub model, just like RX).
- The queries are compiled into expression trees, and executed on the server (which minimizes network traffic, as only relevant results are returned from the server).

  - If we want queries to be filtered client side, then its easy - just do a client side filter on the results returned from pushqa.
- Its literally 1% of the pain, 1% of the boilerplate code, and 10x the usability of [Tibco](http://www.tibco.com). I wrote RX wrappers for Tibco and it was a nightmare to get it correct (Tibco has more [corner cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_case) than a tub of [dodecahedrons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron)). Unless you need to connect to legacy mainframe clients, or want to multicast to hundreds of clients over UDP, or want to waste a kings random in licensing fees, this solution is far superior to Tibco.
- Its free.
- Its open source.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

RX has built in support for using .NET Remoting to cross process boundaries.

If you install the NuGet package `rx-remoting`, it will install the assembly `System.Reactive.Runtime.Remoting.dll` which provides support for cross-process RX messages.

For demo code from Microsoft, see [RX Across Processes](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a55abdf0-631f-41c7-941e-56c4f2ba7544/rx-across-processes?forum=rx). I've just tested the code on this page, and it works nicely. In order to get it to compile, you will need to add the following references:

- [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/): `Reactive Extensions - Main Library` (search for `reactive extensions main`)
- [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/): `Reactive Extensions - .NET Remoting Support` (search for `reactive extensions remoting`)
- `System.Runtime.Remoting` (add as a normal reference, this assembly ships with .NET)

The Channel 9 video mentioned by @theburningmonk is also interesting to watch.

**Update**

Unfortuantely, this solution has one large limitation: you can only have one client process listening (all subsequent clients cannot connect). [Pushqa](http://blog.petegoo.com/Pushqa/) solves this problem (see my other answer). Essentially, any library which implements RX on top of a pub/sub signalling bus should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason that a framework couldn't be devised for doing that.  The framework would have to provide a means to address remote objects, generate proxies for them, then marshal the activity of the remote object across the application boundaries (i.e. through socket communication).  .NET Remoting may be a suitable option for implementing this.  WCF would be even better.

Comment: So as the framework stands right now, you can't just call a remote server and get an IObservable and subscribe to it? Which makes sense as Rx would need to know where and how to make those callbacks and surely can't magically figure those out by itself! lol

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifically bound to using Rx as the solution to your problem? WCF provides duplex services, which have the ability for clients to register callback endpoints to a service. The service may then initiate calls back to its clients as necessary. It is effectively a remoted observer pattern. If RX is a must, then it should be fairly strait forward to wrap WCF duplex services with an RX support framework, allowing your clients to "transparently" observe service behavior with IObservable.

Comment: We're not bound to using Rx as the solution, just exploring different possibilities. A duplex WCF service has also popped up but would be nice to be able to use Rx to deal with more complex composite events.