# How to return an IObservable<T> over WCF?

Tags: wcf, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I am wondering if it's possible to return an `IObservable<T>` over WCF?

The aim of this is to return a list of progress update events, followed by the final result.

### Update

WCF is terrible for anything but the simplest request/response use case. Tried, and utterly failed, to get it working with events, and ended up using another solution instead.

WCF is really showing its age now. It's overly slow, overly complex, bloated and difficult to use, and certainly not recommended for any greenfield projects.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202545/can-reactive-extensions-rx-be-used-across-process-or-machine-boundaries

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497557/how-to-transmit-an-observablecollection-in-real-time-from-wcf-service-to-wpf-c

Comment: Never used it myself, but maybe [Rxx have exactly what you need](https://rxx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Networking&referringTitle=Documentation#WCF)

Comment: Similar question, similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230561/how-to-get-an-iobservable-back-from-web-api

Comment: I disagree that WCF is terrible for anything but the simplest use cases.   Just like anything else, it's all about using the proper tools for the job - sometimes that will be WCF, sometimes it won't.

Comment: I actually said it's terrible for anything but the simplest request/response use cases. As soon as you want to do pub/sub, or react to events, or decouple the sender and receiver, or have persistent message queues, or avoid things breaking if the server doesnt respond within the 30-second timeout, or have more than 50 clients connecting to a server, then you have to switch to some other solution. There are plenty of solutions out there that do all of the above, including simplistic request/response, in a much simpler way.